# How to export JPanel to pdf using iText7 with embedded font introduced in JPanel, asymmetric paper margins, and points positioning

Tags: itext7

I have no prior iText 5 experience but only started reading about iText 7 less than one month ago. I have a fairly complicated task of converting JPanel displays within a master JTabbedPane into pdf with several simultaneous requirements.  I use Swing to specify font and need to embed the font in the pdf.  I need to specify asymmetric pdf margins and distribute top versus bottom, as well as left versus right margins evenly that each JPanel dynamically left open on a landscape US paper.  My generic Java program uses per pixel x and y positioning of all JComponents and the program dynamically knows the x and y extent of each completed JPanel display depending on data content of multiple stacked JTables on each JPanel.  Using 100 pixels per inch, my JPanels will not need scaling to fit the landscape US letter size paper using my specified margins.

I made three separate searches on developers.itextpdf.com with queries of "export JTable to pdf", "export JPanel to pdf", and "export JFrame to pdf" but found no results whether I filter with iText 5 or 7.  The same queries typed into the general internet browser search box turned up multiple results from Stack Overflow (such as [How2: Add a JPanel to a Document then export to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517907/how2-add-a-jpanel-to-a-document-then-export-to-pdf)) and miscellaneous sources.  However, all the solutions are iText 5 dependent because they all use PdfTemplate and PdfContentByte which are absent from iText 7, and a different version of PdfWriter with getInstance method.  However, iText7 export JPanel to pdf shows no result on Stackoverflow.  Since I started after iText 7 has been introduced, I prefer to code my JPanel to pdf conversion with iText 7 if someone can point me how to do it.

Even with the iText 5 solution, how can I be sure that my single Java font specified in my JComponents get transferred into the intermediate Graphics2D (if iText 7 also uses it) and properly linked up with an iText font embedding call.  Additional things I have to tinker with are converting 100 pixels per inch in JPanel to 72 pts per inch on pdf, and the placement of pdf media box for proper margins. I hope simple mathematics with some special rounding attentions are all that's needed for the tinkering part.  Please allow me to thank in advance for any forth coming help.

Comment: Now that have spent some time learning and coding in iText 5, I accidentally bumped into http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/itext/5792/pdf-creation-itext-5-versus-itext-7#t=201612312058074634512 which compares the ways of creating pdf file with iText 5 versus iText 7.  I think I will try to piece together the backend of converting JPanel to pdf and hope that will work with iText 7.

Comment: No luck.  The back end is missing PdfGraphics2D.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but went for a much simpler solution. It is very easy to convert a Swing component into a Java Image, in much the same way you would take a screenshot of the running app. Once you have a big `BufferedImage` containing your `JPanel` contents, you can write it straight into a PDF Document. Then you don't need to mimic any of the Swing code being used to populate the `JTabbedPane` at all.

Here are some code fragments to help you out. Suppose your app creates a JPanel containing Swing elements like `JLabel`'s and the like. To capture this as a Java image, you could do:

```
JPanel myPan = createPanelForTab1();   <<  your main app code does this

// Take a snapshot of myPan as a Java image
BufferedImg jImg = new BufferedImmage(myPan.getWidth(),
                                      myPan.getHeight(),
                                      BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
myPan.paint(jImg.createGraphics());
```

Then convert the Java Image to an iText Image (they are different things). You might also want to scale this image down a bit to fit on a page:

```
itextpdf.layout.element.Image itextImg = new Image(
                                            ImageDataFactory.create(jImg, null));
itextImg.scaleToFit(400.0f, 9999.9f);     // (if it's too big)
```

Adding this img to a PDF Document is as simple as:

```
itextImg.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
document.add(new Paragraph(iTextImg));
```

Perhaps this is the way to go?
(Note: Since you are taking a screenshot, you don't need to worry about any font requirements in the PDF. On the downside, though, there is no text from the Java app in the PDF so you can't search it, for example.)

Comment: Your suggestion is a more automated version of my manual steps,  which consist of repeating Linux Screenshot to capture single JTabbedpane  "png" files.  Libreoffice Draw can export "png" to single screen "pdf" files and then merged with pdftk.  The converted "pdf" file proclaims all standard font or embedded font but show empty font names.  I am able to embed fonts with iText5, but I have to get around the issues with iText5 repeating or not showing individual JTabbedpane contents, which problem I had posted earlier on this exchange.  Thanks. Ting